# Renaming Controller classes in MonoTouch MonoDevelop

Tags: xamarin.ios, monodevelop

What is the the best way to rename a class which inherits a UIViewController and has a designer.cs class linked to a storyboard?

I first tried to Rename the .cs file in MonoDevelop. This worked but the designer.cs file did not get renamed with it, and neither did the class name.

I then renamed the class name. This successfully changed the class name in both the .cs and .designer.cs files but still did not change the .designer.cs filename. It also did not change the name of the "Custom Class" for the controller in Xcode.

So in XCode I changed the name of the Custom Class and saved then switched back to MonoDevelop , to my horror it had created a new .cs with the same name as the renamed one and a new .designer.cs file which it put under the original (renamed) .cs file next to the old (not renamed) a.designer.cs file!

Can anyone tell me the sequence of steps I should have taken?

Comment: I've always had to manually rename the *.designer.cs file in Finder, then open the *.csproj file and manually edit it in a text editor.  I don't have exact steps though, hopefully one of the Xamarin guys can enlighten us.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Renaming the file is tricky, since MD doesn't support renaming grouped files. You'd have to manually edit the csproj, or remove the files from the project, rename in Finder, and add them back.

Renaming the class is somewhat easier, but the key is to understand that the class actually has two names - the .NET name, and the Obj-C name. Renaming the .NET name should be easy, you can simply use the rename command in MD.

The Obj-C name is applied to the class on the [Register("SomeName")] attribute, and is the name that's used in xibs and in Xcode. However, beware that MonoDevelop will attempt to create .NET counterparts of any classes that it thinks were created in Xcode. This means you should change the Obj-C name in MonoDevelop first, then switch to Xcode and change the Custom Class there.

Answer (score 1):

You have to go into the .csproj file and add a  tag. For example:

```
   <Compile Include="MainWindow.cs" />
    <Compile Include="MainWindow.designer.cs">
      <DependentUpon>MainWindow.cs</DependentUpon>
    </Compile>
```

This will then show the correct relationship between the files in the MonoDevelop project window.

Incidentally, my experience so far is that this dependency is purely for convenience. Add the new designer.cs file into the solution and the code compiles just fine: dependency seems to be a sort of documentation.

ALSO: To delete or rename these dependent files, you can't do that in the MonoDevelop project pane: you do have to go to Finder (if you're in OSX, Explorer if you're in Windows) and deal with the files there, to rename or otherwise manipulate them, THEN repair the MonoDevelop csproj file by hand. The good news is, it's not hard, and it works fine when you do this, and you get a cool new hardcore understanding about how the project is knit together.

Answer (score 0):

Many people also has to think about the version control system. This way works for me:

1. Quit MonoDevelop
2. In the version control system, rename the files
3. Open the csproj file in a text editor - search&replace
4. Open MonoDevelop
5. Open the XxxViewController.cs - search&replace
6. Open the XxxViewController.designer.cs - search&replace
7. Open the XxxViewController.xib - search&replace

You might be tempted to use Refactor/Rename instead of search & replace in step 5 but that will cause MonoDevelop to rename XxxViewController.designer.cs to XxxViewController_1.cs for some reason.

Also, you might be tempted to remove the files from the project before renaming them in the version control system and then add them back into your project again (so that you won't have to edit the csproj file manually). This will work but the "DependentUpon" part will disappear from the csproj file, which causes the designer file to not be below its counterpart. No big deal but it looks less nice in the Solution Explorer.

Answer (score 0):

I tried all the solutions above and didn't work. Finally I just used the "Replace in Files" looking the whole solution. After that I did a "Rebuild" in the project and worked fine.